# Decrease Speed value LUA

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

How to increase `movementSpeed` by decreasing  `star1.movementSpeed = 10000;` with -1 every 
10 seconds.

i have tried this, but can't figure out what i am doing wrong

```
function initStar()
local star1 = {}
star1.imgpath = "Star1.png"; --Set Image Path for Star
star1.movementSpeed = 10000; --Determines the movement speed of star
table.insert(starTable, star1); --Insert Star into starTable
end --END initStar()    


 local function star1incr() -- increments Speed value every time it is called
 movementSpeed = movementSpeed - 1
 star1.movementSpeed = "movementSpeed: " .. movementSpeed 
 end

 timer.performWithDelay(10000, star1incr, 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by using

```
   local function star1incr()
        starTable[1].movementSpeed = starTable[1].movementSpeed - 1
        print( "- 1" )
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a variable you can share between `initStar()` and `star1incr()` (btw, "increment `movementSpeed` by decreasing `...movementSpeed` doesn't sound right); something like this may work:

```
local star1 = {}

function initStar()
  star1.imgpath = "Star1.png" --Set Image Path for Star
  star1.movementSpeed = 10000 --Determines the movement speed of star
end --END initStar()    


local function star1incr()
  star1.movementSpeed = star1.movementSpeed - 1
end

timer.performWithDelay(10000, star1incr, 0)
```

`star1` variable will be shared between `initStar` and `star1incr` functions (in Lua terminology it's called an upvalue).